# Correct usage of a sentence with "is/was"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses

I have a question regarding the usage of a sentence.

Option A:

> Today is your last day to complete this task.

Option B:

> Today was your last day to complete this task.

I have a doubt, so when I'm referring to "today", it would still be the present, so that would suggest the usage of *is* rather than *was*.

Considering a situation, let's say, it's the end of the workday at 6PM in the evening, would it be fine to refer to *was* instead of *is*, here "today" would refer to work-day rather than a calendar day?

Is the usage of *was* acceptable or is it incorrect?

Comment: Yes; I won't give an 'answer', since I'll almost certainly only be able to find anecdotal evidence, but your thinking is totally correct. 'Today is ...' means you still have the opportunity (though obviously less than 24 hours, as 'today' is already under way). 'Today was ...' means you've lost your opportunity (though obviously, as 'today' still applies, the 24-hour day isn't yet over. It could be you've already missed the deadline [as you say, perhaps the end of the working day] or that you've too much work to cram into what's left of the 24 hours. Both are acceptable usages.) // There ...

Comment: _is_ another valid possibility: 'Today was your last day to complete this task. But you're lucky; the deadline has been extended by a week.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar examples from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-simple-or-present-perfect), though with different tenses, can explain the difference between the two situations:

> I ***didn’t have*** any lunch today.

means that today is not finished but it is almost the end of the day and ***past lunchtime*** (there is no possibility to have lunch *today*).

> I ***haven’t had*** any lunch today.

means it is still today and ***not too late*** to have lunch.

In both situations the time interval is ***today***: it includes the moment of speech, but is not limited to it. The day is not finished.

Your option A could be re-written:

> You haven't completed this task and your deadline is today. (it's your last chance to do it)

and Option B

> You didn't complete this task today (and you missed the deadline).

In your sentence *Today ***was*** your last day to complete this task,* the past tense indicates that the speaker refers to a past interval/time included in what we call ***today***, but prior to the moment of speech (***an earlier moment today***) with the intention to state that it is too late to change anything about the matter expressed in the sentence. Past tense is generally used to indicate

> Definite time in the past ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-simple-i-worked))

The particularity of this sentence is simply that this past moment is included in the period called ***today*** and choosing either Option A or Option B to express it, will indicate if the matter discussed can still be subject to change or not.

Note that you can have similar situations with time phrases formed with the determiner ***this***: ***this week, this month, this summer, this year***, etc.

Consider:

> This week ***was** busy* due to the promotion of our new app Sorted, and the
> preparation of AngelHack Hong Kong. ([source](https://medium.com/@harryworld/where-are-the-developers-a92e3f4992a4)) (the week approaches its end
> and the speaker looks back at the achievements that were accomplished earlier in the week).

and

> This week ***is*** *busy* for many of us. Shopping, parties, holiday gatherings. It is a go, go, go week. ([source](https://www.lynnskitchenadventures.com/last-minute-christmas-candy-recipes/)) (the speaker has in mind the coming week, or the moment of speech is somewhere at the beginning of the week)